Desktop not responding after interrupting fc-cache
Last night, I was configuring some fonts for use with polybar.
I ran the command
fc-cache -fv
It was taking a while so had it on in the background while working on something else.
Came back and my laptop had run dead. Rebooted it, and now I can hear my harddrive working hard, and a program "gjs" keeps continually opening and closing. No apps can be run, and on attempt to run them they mouse just has the circle next to it, or I cant maximize them.
Is there a way I can fix this without having to completely reinstall ubuntu?
Ubuntu version 24.04
Thanks :>
Edit: rebuilt font cache using no gui terminal and it works again

You've not provided any Ubuntu product/release details; but given your description (and an incomplete font cache) I'd have expected you to login to a text terminal & corrected your corrupted cache before attempting to login to a GUI.  Did you attempt this?  For us to advise accurately, we do need to know what you're running (ie. software stack details).

Thanks for providing release (still not details; Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Server? Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Desktop etc, though likely desktop but its best if you're specific with details), but have you logged into a text terminal and re-created the font cache?  If I have any problem, I usually boot live system & check disk health (ie. SMART; rather than do this monthly or schedule I do it on any problem), perform file-system checks, then boot & correct anything that wasn't complete; ie. in your case that would be I re-create font caches before attempting to use them, ie. before login with GUI if desktop

yes i am trying this now i am new to linux thanks for the help

ahh i rebuilt fonts and it worked i feel that should have been the obvious solution thankss

Feel free to write your own answer then, outlining what you did to solve the problem (do it below).  If you want to mention me that's fine, but if you accept your own answer (in time) you'll gain some rep on the site.  :)

Ah i see will do that now :>

I rebuilt the font cache using 'fc-cache -fv' again in the no gui terminal (using CTRL + Alt + F3) as the normal one didnt load.
Now everything works as normal :D
Thanks to @guiverc
